# Extracting a value from key-value pair from a file in JenkinsFile

Tags: shell, groovy, sed, grep, jenkins-pipeline

There is are two file in a GIT repository (abc.toml and JenkinsFile)...
abc.toml looks like:

```
[env]
    APPLICATION = 'xxx'
    COMPONENT = 'xxx'
    Z_VERSION='0.0.1'
    AAAS_FLA='xxx'
    CONF_VERSION='0.0.80'
    SVC_VERSION='0.0.93'
```

Now in JenkinsFile I have to extract the value of SVC_VERSION in a variable.

I am trying:

```
node{
 stage('Deploy'){
 def SVC_VERSION =  sh returnStdout: true, script: cat abc.toml | grep SVC_VERSION|sed -e "s/.*=//g" -e "s/['| ]//g"
 }
}
```

But I am getting a error:

```
org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
WorkflowScript: 16: expecting '}', found '|' @ line 16, column 71.
   rue, script: cat abc.toml | grep SVC
                             ^
```

How can I correct it?
Expected result is SVC_VERSION variable should get 0.0.93

Comment: The basic error in the posted code is that the script: parameter should be a quoted string, e.g.```sh returnStdout: true, script: '''cat abc.toml | grep SVC_VERSION|sed -e "s/.*=//g" -e "s/['| ]//g" ''' ```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest is probably to use the built-ins as @yorammi mentioned:

See https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#readproperties-read-properties-from-files-in-the-workspace-or-text

For instance you could do:

```
node{
 stage('Deploy'){
   def props = readProperties file: 'abc.toml'
   def SVC_VERSION = props['SVC_VERSION']

   echo "SVC_VERSION = ${SVC_VERSION}"
 }
}
```

The advantage is that you can read the file from the node workspace.

Answer (score 0):

This is working fine :

```
def SVC_VERSION = sh returnStdout: true, script: "cat ./abc.toml | grep SVC_VERSION | sed -e \"s/.*=//g\" -e \"s/['| ]//g\" "
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is `awk` version which is IMHO sample to read:

```
def SVC_VERSION = sh returnStdout: true, script: "awk -F\' '/SVC_VERSION/ {print $2}' ./abc.toml"
```

Answer (score 0):

As a standard procedure, I use .properties file to store environment variables.
Your file will appear as-
envt.properties:

```
 APPLICATION =xxx
 COMPONENT =xxx
 Z_VERSION=0.0.1
 AAAS_FLA=xxx
 CONF_VERSION=0.0.80
 SVC_VERSION=0.0.93
```

I use this groovy code to retrieve any property value:

```
 def prop= new Properties()
   new File("envt.properties").withInputStream { 
      stream -> prop.load(stream) 
   }
   def propConfig = new ConfigSlurper().parse(prop)
def SVC_VERSION=propConfig.SVC_VERSION
def CONF_VERSION=propConfig.CONF_VERSION
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: This code will only read the file from the master, not from the node workspace (because it's using the File api). You can use `readFile` , or better `loadProperties()` otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a *bash* command, I suggest that you use Groovy code.

Use the `readFile` method to read the file, and then loop the lines and for each line, separating the *key* from the *value*.

Answer (score 0):

For those who are using **Jenkins Shared Libraries**, this is how I managed to do it with the help of **[TomlSlurper](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/gapi/groovy/toml/TomlSlurper.html)** and Grape, a JAR dependency manager embedded into Groovy.

*Jenkinsfile*

```
// Import TOML parser from Maven Central
@Grapes(@Grab(group='org.apache.groovy', module='groovy-toml', version='4.0.12'))
import groovy.toml.TomlSlurper

String getAppVersion() {
  String tomlTxt = readFile './pyproject.toml'
  def toml = new TomlSlurper().parseText(tomlTxt)
  return toml.app.version
}
```

*pyproject.toml*

```ini
[app]
version = 15.0
```